# jboss-as-maven-plugin deploy location

Tags: jboss7.x, maven-plugin

I deployed an ejb jar through jboss-as-maven-plugin in JBoss AS 7.1. The jar is deployed properly but I can't seem to find the location of jar in the server. I checked the **standalone/deployments** folder but it is not there. This deployment through jboss as maven plugin seems to create a content file added in the standalone/data/ folder; when I remove that content folder the deployed jar is removed.

Any idea whether the actual jar is located in the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location of the JAR shouldn't really matter as it should never just be deleted. There are several ways to undeploy/remove a deployment which would be the appropriate path to take.

1. Use the maven plugin to remove the deployment: `mvn jboss-as:undeploy`
2. Use CLI to remove the deployment: `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect "undeploy $YOUR_DEPLOYMENT_NAME"`
3. Use the web console to remove the deployment

That said in a standalone server the deployments are placed in the `data` directory.

Comment: The deploy/undeploy works fine. If it is in the data directory then the compiled classes and resources are stored there?

Comment: Correct. The compiled classes and resources are stored in the `data` directory.